# htaccess: Combine IP-Whitelist with htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, .htpasswd, whitelist

my .htaccess looks like this:

```
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "123.456.12.34" AllowIP
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowIP
```

I want to combine this "whitelist" with a htpasswd: If a whitelisted IP accesses the server, a password request should be displayed.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following lines solved it:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```